# Moving postgres db folder of a rails application from one system to another with all data

Tags: postgresql, docker

I am running my rails application in docker. So get my code via git and all environment dependencies via docker. My aim is to develop and access my application in any system for this now I need the database also.. Present i have some data in local PostgreSQL db folder.

I tried moving that postgresql db folder from my local to drive. Also get connected in another system but got some db config issue..
Now I need to move it from local to drive and can get wherever i need. How to do it?

Comment: Why don't use SQL dump instead of folder with system files?

Answer (score 1):

you should not use the files of your current postgresql for another postgresql instance , instead use `pg_dump` to take a logical backup of your database and restore your data in the new instance with the logical backup you took from the old one.
I suggest reading the the [official doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/backup.html) for more detailed steps
Hope that helps!